# DB2 force application failed to kill load job

Tags: linux, database, db2, db2-luw

We want to kill running load job. I have executed `db2 force application (<agentid>)` and `db2 force application all`, but still the load job is not killed.

DB2 version is 10.5 and server is Linux.

```
:~> db2 list utilities

ID                               = 5
Type                             = LOAD
Database Name                    = qts
Member Number                    = 0
Description                      = [LOADID: 106.2015-10-17-08.37.11.389985.0 (65530;32770)] [9.63.33.62.39376.151017123551] OFFLINE LOAD ASC AUTOMATIC INDEXING INSERT COPY NO TCS.ASSETS
Start Time                       = 10/17/2015 08:37:11.641208
State                            = Executing
Invocation Type                  = User
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is. The `FORCE APPLICATION` command is asynchronous and it does not guarantee that the session is terminated immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a bit of information. 
Regarding "force application", Yes.that's asynchronous operation. 
What happens is DB2 will put force flag to target app handle(or EDU). 
Depending on what the application handle(EDU) is doing, it can be force right away or wait until the app handle reach the point of checking the interrupt flag.
For example, an app handle doing rollback can't be forced in the middle.
And there are lots of conditions.

But in general, load job should be able to be forced by 'db2 force application'.

If you want to know why your job didn't kill, you may need to check with IBM DB2 support by collecting the following information.

```
$ db2pd -stack all
(Stack dump will be generated in db2dump directory.)
$ db2pd -latches
$ db2pd -edus
$ db2pd -apinfo -db <dbname>
$ db2pd -util
$ db2pd -db <dbname> -locks
```

Comment: Hi Juan,  After executing query $ db2pd -util. It shows following running load stat:

Comment: db2pd -util
Utilities:
Progress:
Address            ID         PhaseNum   CompletedWork                TotalWork                    StartTime           Description           
0x000000010620C1C8 1699       1          0 bytes                      0 bytes                      Wed Oct 17 10:09:53 SETUP                 
0x000000010620C380 1699       2          0 rows                       0 rows                  Wed Oct 17 10:09:56 LOAD.                        

How to kill this load job. As db2 "force force application <agent_id>" is not working